# How to run a procedure if a module is successfully imported in Maya

Tags: python, procedure, maya

I am just finishing a script that cam be run as a module. I had a procedure call in the original script so it ran when it was imported, opening my GUI.

Say I want to open this window if the module imports correctly. How do I do this?

```
i.e 
try:
 import maya.cmds as cmds
except:
   pass
```

#procedure defined here

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    createGUI()
```

When I import my script as module in Maya my GUI doesn't open, what am I doing wrong? 
Thanks

However if I use pydoc to do documentation and the previous format the it does output correctly. But if I call any procedure outside of the if statement it does.
Will upload my code later today.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the `__name__` variable in your module. When you import this in Maya it might be part of other module , thus it won't be `'__main__'`. 
Also does this work :

```
import myModule 
myModule.createGUI()
```

Comment: yes that works ^ but i need to get the GUI to open automatically

Comment: When you print `__name__` do you get `'__main__'`  or you get the name of your module instead ? I am pretty sure it won't be `'__main__'`

Comment: if I print name in the script editor I get '__main__' ... I am quite confused. In my seperate python file, the gui opens if I just call createGUI at the bottom. However when trying to pydoc it says cmds is not defined in fhe try, and doesn't write documentation to html file.

Comment: I meant putting a print statement in your module `print __name__` . When you import the module or reload it it should print the name of the module, but because you are running it from Maya it should not be `'__main__'`

Comment: it prints myModule name. So does that mean I need to write. 
if __name__ == 'MyModule' etc
 createGUI

Comment: Okay, so now the GUI opens in maya now. But my pydoc wont output now.

Comment: Is there a way to do both?

Comment: I am not sure about which pydoc you are talking about. Mabe include a better code snippet. I think you should reedit your original question to clarify this so we don't comment here all over again.

Answer (score 0):

if **name** == **main** is the standard idiom for 'if i am running in the interpreter as a script'.  But all statements lying loose in the module will be executed at import time. If you want to run the code whenever the module is imported, just put the executable code down at the bottom of the script (so all names are defined before being called) and it will run in both places.

That said: *don't*.  You really don't want to write code that runs on import beyond trivial initializations and module-specific setups. It's far better to just write it like:

```
def create_my_gui():
   # do stuff

if name == "__main__":
   create_my_gui()
```

and then call the module from whatever code imported it in Maya:

```
import myModule
myModule.create_my_gui()
```

That way you get to decide when the gui pops up instead of having it appear every time you pop open the module.  Otherwise you can't peek into the module to grab a function or class without causing the gui to run.